How to get Flutter's ping_dart results
I'm trying to build a ping test android app.
An error occurs when using the ping_dart package.
Please help.
 void startPing() async {
    final ping = Ping('google.com', count: 5);
    ping.stream.listen((event) {
      print(event);
    });
  }

Result :
I/flutter (23733): PingError(response:PingResponse(seq:1), error:requestTimedOut)
I/flutter (23733): PingError(response:PingResponse(seq:2), error:requestTimedOut)
I/flutter (23733): PingError(response:PingResponse(seq:3), error:requestTimedOut)
I/flutter (23733): PingError(response:PingResponse(seq:4), error:requestTimedOut)
I/flutter (23733): PingSummary(transmitted:5, received:0), time: 4085 ms, Errors: [requestTimedOut, requestTimedOut, requestTimedOut, requestTimedOut, noReply]

Flutter's emulator's Android language setting is in English.
